# cannot manipulate string with angular filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I am an angular newbie and I study the  book "Angular JS by example" and I try to create my own filter. (pp. 93-94).

In my controller this is the string I want to manipulate
`procedure: "Assume a position, with feet together .\Slightly bend your knees, .\While in air, bring your legs out .\ As you are moving your legs outward"`

and then I sanitise it

```
$scope.trustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.currentExercise.details.procedure);
```

Since this is an SPA , the filter is in the `description-panel.ejs` file, that is inside `workout.ejs`, that is inside `index.ejs`

`description-panel.ejs` has

```
<div class="panel-body" ng-bind-html ="trustedHtml | myLineBreakFilter"> </div>
```

`workout.ejs` has

```
<div id="video-panel" class="col-sm-3" ng-include="'description-panel.ejs'">
```

and `index.ejs` has

```
<script src="/javascripts/7MinWorkout/filters.js"></script>
```

`filter.js` has the filter

```
angular.module('7minWorkout').filter('myLineBreakFilter', function () {
    return function (input) {
        var str = input;
        var br = "</br></br>";
        var position = str.indexOf(".");

        var output = [str.slice(0, position), br, str.slice(position)].join('');    

        return output ; 
    }
});
```

The filter should replace all the `.` with `</br></br>`.

This does not work and I get no text at all in my front-end. I get this error in the console

```
TypeError: str.slice is not a function  at filters.js:22
```

Shouldn't basic js stuff like `str.slice` be supported out of the box? What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Try and `console.log(str)` and/or `console.log(typeof str)` to see whether it's string as expected

Comment: @Fissio `typeof` is "object" and `str` is the string , with only the last period replaced by `</br></br>`. But I still cannot see anything on the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$sce.trustAsHtml()` return you an object so slice will not work on it.You can pass that object to `$sce.getTrustedHtml(object)` to obtain the original value and then can apply slice on it.

```
    angular.module('7minWorkout').filter('myLineBreakFilter', function ($sce) {
return function (input) {

var str = $sce.getTrustedHtml(input);
var br = "</br></br>";
var position = str.indexOf(".");

var output = [str.slice(0, position), br, str.slice(position)].join('');    

return $sce.trustAsHtml(output) ; 
}
});
```

Comment: Good idea, but no, it does not work, I get `ReferenceError: $sce is not defined`, which is normal. I could put the filter inside the controller, but will cause more fuss, plus I think the filter on the view is way better and more logic, seperating tasks. I'm still working on it. Any ideas?

Comment: have you added $sce as a dependency?

Comment: @Jungu At the controller ? Yes : `angular.module('7minWorkout').controller('WorkoutController',['$scope', '$interval','$location','$sce',function($scope, $interval,$location,$sce){`. But the controller and the filter are in seperate files.  I guess I could do `$scope.trustedHtml = $sce.getTrustedHtml($scope.currentExercise.details.procedure);` in the controller and leave the filter as is. But I dont know if this is right, because   the page gets an text not a object. Also, there are no breaks

Comment: in filter inject $sce as i have done in answer .filter('myLineBreakFilter', function ($sce) {

Comment: @Jungu I did and now I get no errors. After `ar str = $sce.getTrustedHtml(input);` I do `console.log("str "+str); console.log("typeof str  "+typeof str);` . Type is "string" and the string has breaks, but in the page I see no breaks. Now I am confused, I am sorry, but I dont get what went wrong

Comment: return your output so your last line in filter will be return  $sce.trustAsHtml(output); instead of return output

Comment: @Jungu Ah, you da man!!! It worked. You can compile this to a complete answer, so I can vote you. Thanks fot your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this add this before the splice

```
str.toString();
str.splice(//pass parameters);
```